# MS Access - Query bringing in "new record" row

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query that will be populating a form and then the form will allow the data set to be edited. The issue I am having is that the query is pulling the last row that is normally used to add a new record. This results in having a row that looks shows all fields as blank, but leaves one field with "null".

I played around with the query and was able to find a workaround by selecting "distinct" records, problem is that when you select with distinct, you cannot edit the data set. Is there any other way around this?

I can upload an example of the database if needed. 
Thanks!

edit: picture to show the issue: https://imgbomb.com/i/?rO1sp

Comment: if your query is getting an empty/new row then it sounds like your query isn't working. test your query in the query designer, not in the form, to make sure it's getting the row you need. (what's missing here?)

Comment: @wazz I have verified that the query is working (I built the query outside of the form and have tested again just to be sure). The query is also bringing back all the other data that I need, but for some reason it still captures that one last row.

Comment: @wazz a picture to show what the issue I am having https://i.imgbomb.com/RN8Qa.png
you will notice it is most annoying when you search and do not find any matches, the form will still show the "null" record